# How do I programmatically trigger "hoverintent" on an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, hoverintent

I am using Tristen Brown's [hoverintent library](https://github.com/tristen/hoverintent), which is a pure Javascript version of the jQuery [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) library.

I have two elements `first` and `second`.

The `second` element has `hoverintent` handlers which causes a tooltip to appear above that element. When I manually hover over `second`, the tooltip appears as expected.

I would like to trigger the tooltip of `second` programmatically. For example, to make interacting with the `first` element cause the tooltip of the `second` element to appear. I have attempted to do this using jQuery `trigger`. I am able to `trigger` mouseover handlers, but not any hoverIntent.

Any suggestions?

Here is my Javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var first = document.getElementById('first');
  var second = document.getElementById('second');

  $(first).mouseover(function(){
    $(second).trigger({ type:"mouseover", clientX:"350", clientY:"105" });
    $(second).trigger({ type:"mousemove", clientX:"350", clientY:"105" });
  });

  hoverintent(second, function(e) {
    this.className = 'on';
  }, function(e) {
    this.className = 'off';
  });

  $(second).mouseover(function(){
    console.log("mouseover");
  });
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src='http://tristen.ca/hoverintent/dist/hoverintent.min.js'></script>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="padding:100px;">
    <ul class='examples'>
      <li id='first'>
        Trigger
      </li>
      <li id='second'>
        hoverintent
        <span class='popup'>Hi there</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The full JS bin is here:

http://jsbin.com/kumeva/4/edit?js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to trigger the tooltip of second by mousing over the first element.

You can dispatch a sequence of mouse events to `#second` and keep the *hoverintent* code and the dispatch code completely separate like this:

```
// Hoverintent code
$(document).ready(function() {
  var second = document.getElementById('second');
  hoverintent(second, function(e) {
    this.className = 'on';
  }, function(e) {
    this.className = 'off';
  });
});

///////////////////////////////////

// Dispatch code
$(document).ready(function() {
  var first = document.getElementById('first');
  var second = document.getElementById('second');
  $(first).on("mouseover", function(){
    // Send a mouseover to wake hoverintent
    var event = new MouseEvent("mouseover");
    second.dispatchEvent(event);

    // Send a mousemove trigger the internal hover code
    event = new MouseEvent("mousemove");
    second.dispatchEvent(event);
  });

  $(first).on("mouseout", function(){
    // Cancel the hover code
    var event = new MouseEvent("mouseout");
    second.dispatchEvent(event);
  });
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsbin.com/caxehazavi/1/watch?js,output)

Comment: Ah, just to give more context. I'm trying to pass messages between iframes with `postMessage` and need to trigger the hoverIntent of an element programmatically. So attaching hoverIntent to the first element doesn't work in this context.

Comment: Gotcha. See my updated answer and demo. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Awesome that works, thank you! Very curious why jQuery's `trigger` doesn't work, though.

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code of the librairy, it seam that it rely on **mouseover** and **mouseout**. To determine the mouse position, it seam to use **clientX** and **clientY**, not **pageX/Y**.

Source file : https://github.com/tristen/hoverintent/blob/gh-pages/index.js

Comment: I also see that it relies on `mousemove` as well. I changed the example to `clientX` and `clientY` but still not quite working.